# errors when compiling class in c++

Tags: c++, oop, compilation, compiler-errors

I tried to create a class for 3-D vector in c++, but there are some errors. I have learnt a little bit of oop in python before, but I'm still pretty new to oop and c++. I created the header file threevector.h, the file for the class threevector.cpp and the main program file main.cpp. I just want to know what I have done wrong.

```
// threevector.h
#ifndef THREEVECTOR_H
#define THREEVECTOR_H
#include <iostream>

class threevector {
    private:
        double xcoord, ycoord, zcoord;

    public:
        threevector();
        threevector(double x, double y, double z, char type);
        void print ();      
};
#endif // THREEVECTOR_H


//threevector.cpp
#include "threevector.h"
#include <cmath>

threevector() {
    xcoord = 0.0;
    ycoord = 0.0;
    zcoord = 0.0;
}

threevector(double x, double y, double z, char type) {
    if (type == 'c') {
        // cartesian coordinate
        xcoord = x;
        ycoord = y;
        zcoord = z;
    } 
    else if (type == 'p') {
        // polar coordinate
        // x = r, y = phi, z = theta
        xcoord = x*sin(y)*cos(z);
        ycoord = x*sin(y)*sin(z);
        zcoord = x*cos(y);
        }
}

void print () {
    std::cout << xcoord << '\t' << ycoord << '\t' << zcoord << std::endl;
}


// main.cpp
#include "threevector.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    threevector v0;
    v0.print();

    threevector v1(-1,2,4.384,'c');
    cout << "v1 = ";
    v1.print();

    return 0;
}
```

The following are the error messages I get:

```
main.cpp(.text+0x15): undefined reference to 'threevector::threevector()'
main.cpp(.text+0x15): undefined reference to 'threevector::print()'
main.cpp(.text+0x15): undefined reference to 'threevector::threevector::threevector(double, double, double, char)'
main.cpp(.text+0x15): undefined reference to 'threevector::print()'
[Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I still get the same error messages even after I have added threevector::

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined your `threevector`'s methods wrong. It should be:

```
threevector::threevector() {
    xcoord = 0.0;
    ycoord = 0.0;
    zcoord = 0.0;
}

threevector::threevector(double x, double y, double z, char type) {
    if (type == 'c') {
        // cartesian coordinate
        xcoord = x;
        ycoord = y;
        zcoord = z;
    } 
    else if (type == 'p') {
        // polar coordinate
        // x = r, y = phi, z = theta
        xcoord = x*sin(y)*cos(z);
        ycoord = x*sin(y)*sin(z);
        zcoord = x*cos(y);
        }
}

void threevector::print () {
    std::cout << xcoord << '\t' << ycoord << '\t' << zcoord << std::endl;
}
```

All `threevector`'s methods are in `threevector`'s scope.

Don't forget to compile it as same as `main.cpp`:

```
g++ threevector.cpp main.cpp
```

This will be linked properly as `threevector` is in same object file.

Comment: "Each class declares it's own namepace"?

Comment: Don't believe that it is really a namespace, but it has scope *similar* to a namespace.

Comment: I still get the same error messages even after I have added threevector::

Comment: @ChristianHackl that was actually wrong, it is better to say `scope` like chrashmstr pointed.

Comment: @Physicist so it seems you don't compile the `threevector.cpp` file.

Comment: how to make sure threevector.cpp is complied? where do I add the line 'g++ threevector.cpp main.cpp' ?

Comment: @Physicist well, how do you compile your `main.cpp` then?

Comment: good question. I just pressed the 'compile and run' button for the main.cpp (not the threevector.cpp). So in this case how do I compile two files?

Comment: It depends on your IDE. Google how to add a file to the project.

Comment: *" I just pressed the 'compile and run' button"* - That "compile and run button" is just something of your IDE's GUI which launches the real thing (= the compiler). You should learn to use the compiler directly on the command line instead of treating it like a black box.

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined your member function, you only declared them.

If you look at your class definition again:

> ```
> class threevector {
>     private:
>         double xcoord, ycoord, zcoord;
>
>     public:
>         threevector();
>         threevector(double x, double y, double z, char type);
>         void print ();      
> };
> ```

It contains declarations for three member functions:

- `threevector::threevector()`
- `threevector::threevector(double, double, double, char)`
- `threevector::print()`

The `threevector::` part is important - since these are member functions, the class name is part of their own name (or so to speak).

The functions you defined, however, miss the `threevector::` part. For example, you define a function called `print()`, but the name is just a coincidence.

**`threevector::print()` and `print()` are different names and thus different functions.**

Same with the two constructors.

The solution is therefore to use the correct, full names when you define the functions:

```
threevector::threevector() {
    xcoord = 0.0;
    ycoord = 0.0;
    zcoord = 0.0;
}

threevector::threevector(double x, double y, double z, char type) {
    if (type == 'c') {
        // cartesian coordinate
        xcoord = x;
        ycoord = y;
        zcoord = z;
    } 
    else if (type == 'p') {
        // polar coordinate
        // x = r, y = phi, z = theta
        xcoord = x*sin(y)*cos(z);
        ycoord = x*sin(y)*sin(z);
        zcoord = x*cos(y);
        }
}

void threevector::print () {
    std::cout << xcoord << '\t' << ycoord << '\t' << zcoord << std::endl;
}
```

While we're at it, constructors should use initialisation lists, not assignment, at least if that's easily possible:

```
threevector::threevector() :
    xcoord(0.0),
    ycoord(0.0),
    zcoord(0.0)
{
}
```

---

P.S.: Do not confuse this with namespaces. All of this has nothing to do with namespaces.